# add 30 minutes to $when so that after 30 minutes people can't view page anymore in PHP

Tags: php

So after 30 minutes the result page is not visible anymore, I used strtotime.
My code will make it clear, what do I need to put at the { ???? }

```
<?php
    $when = strtotime('2012-10-23 13:39:00');
    if ($when < time()){
        ?> <a href="result.php?">Bekijk de resultaten!</a>
        <?php echo "update every 2 min";
       }
     elseif ( ???? )
     { echo "overtime";}
     else
    {echo "De wedstrijd begint om 13:39 vandaag!";}

?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This sounds like a javascript job and not PHP

Comment: Yep...Javascript unless you use Session Variables to track the time taken on each page load.

Comment: It's linked to a cron job so I don't really see the use of javascript :p

Comment: Guys, he has there a fix time. The result page is show at 13:39 + 30 minutes. So it's not 30 minutes after opening the page. The page will not load after 14:09.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have your question marks:

`elseif (($when + 1800) > time())`

1800 is 30 times 60 seconds (30 minutes in seconds)

Comment: I would have done the same but it should be less than time(), shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks this was what I was missing :D

Answer (score 0):

I assume the main part with the link should be visible at 13:39 to + 30 minutes, so I also corrected the `if` part. The + 30 minutes is in `strtotime` quite sweet. You just type after the time string `+30 minutes`.

```
<?php
  $time = '2012-10-23 13:39:00';
  $startTime = strtotime($time);
  $stopTime = strtotime($time + ' +30 minutes'); 
  if ($startTime > time() && $stopTime < time()) {
    echo "<a href=\"result.php?\">Bekijk de resultaten!</a>";
    echo "update every 2 min";
  }
  elseif ( $stopTime > time() ) {
    echo "overtime";
  } else {
    echo "De wedstrijd begint om 13:39 vandaag!";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks sweet! I'm going to give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the individual components of the date you could also use mktime and add 30 to the minutes value and php would parse it exactly they way you want.  The following two lines would return the exact same values:

```
echo date("n/j/Y H:i:s", mktime(13, 69, 00, 10, 23, 2012));
echo date("n/j/Y H:i:s", mktime(14, 9, 00, 10, 23, 2012));
```

If all you have is the string value then the previously mentioned approaches would work well.